# Why am I getting huge latency issues?

Tags: counter-strike

I have 512 kbps internet plan, but ping is very high during the game. I have done research on it and found others with same speed (512 kbps) but on different ISPs have very low ping during the game. I have try all the common tricks which suggested clean temp, stop other s/w, use game booster etc. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: One of the best things you can do, is get a better internet connection.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to your ISP or the game you're playing: it's just a matter of Internet distance. I would suggest you try to add more detail to your question, namely, if you are connecting to far away servers and if those reports you state are in the same situation as you are.

Comment: You've answered your own question here really, the problem is your ISP.

Comment: If you're sitting on top of a gaming server, ie: you live in the same town it's hosted in, you will see an increase in performance over living say, in another country - this is due to how many hops you'll go through before reaching your location. Do a traceroute to see these when you ping a server. But ultimately 512 kbps internet is not the best for online gaming. (especially competitive)

Comment: change ISP if u see that other ISP giving a lower ping on the same server.

Comment: Are you on DSL, Cable or other? That is an awfully slow 'highspeed' speed.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, internet speed does not affect ping. For example, if you are getting 200ms on 512Kbps then upgrading to 1Mbps will **not** reduce the ping by half.

Ping depends on several factors, the most common ones are (i) the type and quality of your internet connection (ii) the distance between you and the server (iii) the quality of the network route between you and the server.

So, it is pretty much possible to have a fast internet connection with high ping, or to have a high ping on some servers and low ping on others.

I would suggest searching for gaming servers that have low ping for your ISP. Switch your ISP or internet connection only if you have ruled out other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have suggested, you have two real options to deal with network latency, plus a few other things you can try:

**Option 1. Get a faster internet connection**

Whether or not this is possible or worthwhile is dependent on your local ISPs, the cabling to your house, affordability, etc. In any case, it is not a decision we can help with. If you are looking at options, remember that (for online gaming, at least) upload speeds can be just as important as download speeds, as your game client and the server are sending information back and forth all the time.

**Option 2. Connect to a server closer to you**

Obvious in hindsight, but it's something we forget. The internet isn't magic - at its core, it's computers connected by physical cables. The farther apart those computers are, (in this example, your computer and the game server), the farther the signals have to travel, the more intermediate nodes they have to pass through, and the slower things get overall. Try finding a server nearer to you. By the way, this is also why playing on LAN is always so fast - all the machines are on the same local network and the signals do not have very far to travel at all.

**Other things to try**

- Disable any applications that are using your internet connection. That means close torrent or other download apps, get people to stop using Netflix or other streaming services, etc.
- Make sure your firewall is configured to correctly let all relevant traffic through. If for whatever reason it's only letting *some* packets through, your game client may be getting into an unstable state, which can manifest as lag (e.g. if your game client and the server cannot agree on where a player is located)

Comment: You forgot to tell them to directly connect to the modem and hog the internet for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agreeing with Salman here but need to elaborate on a few points... Ultimately, quality seems to be the problem. **The question is is the ISP really the cause of the quality concerns?** They may not be -- at least, exclusively.

First question before you do anything else. **Are you wired or wireless?** If wireless, can you be wired? If so, plug in and try the game then (even if just to test). If that helps, you found your problem. Your wireless connection is the cause. If that doesn't help, try my next step. (Note: I play on wireless, so it is possible if that is your situation but me detailing *how* is out of scope of this question)

While wired, go to [pingtest.net](http://www.pingtest.net/) and run that. What are your scores? If your scores are high (200ms and above), then the *quality* of your ISP is probably low overall and there is nothing you can do but find a new service provider. (The cause isn't your game). If your scores are low-ish (100ms or less), then it could be the firewall in your router or something within your control / network.

Let me know the results and I'll elaborate based on your findings.